# Print all valid combinations of n-pairs of parentheses

Tags: java

Left: As long as we haven’t used up all the left parentheses, we can always insert a left paren.
Right: We can insert a right paren as long as it won’t lead to a syntax error. When will we get a syntax error

```
public class parentheses {

    public static void printPar(int l, int r, char[] str, int count){  //Use recursion method to 
                                                                       // print the parentheses
        if(l == 0 && r == 0){     //if there are no parentheses available, print them out  
            System.out.println(str); //Print out the parentheses
        }

        else{
            if(l > 0){    // try a left paren, if there are some available
                str[count] = '(';
                printPar(l - 1, r, str, count + 1); //Recursion
            }
            if(r > 0){   // try a right paren, if there are some available
                str[count] = ')';
                printPar(l, r - 1, str, count + 1);  //Recursion
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printPar(int count){
        char[] str = new char[count*2];   // Create a char array to store the parentheses
        printPar(count,count,str,0);      //call the printPar method, the parameters are the left,
                                            //the right parentheses, the array to store the 
                                            //parenthese, and the counter
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        printPar(2);  //

    }

}
```

The result should be:

```
(())
()()
```

But what I get is:

```
(())
()()
())(
)(()
)()(
))((
```

Comment: Aren't then an infinite number of valid parentheses? `{ a^N B^n | a is a left paren and b is a right paren}`

Comment: Actually, *any* order of parentheses is valid, so long as the first parenthesis is open, and the last parenthesis is closed, given that at no point the number of closed parens exceeds the number of open parens.

Comment: @Telthien So like this `()))`?

Comment: Realized that about two seconds after posting it. Corrected.

Answer (score 4):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class parentheses {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(prent(2));
    }

    public static List<String> prent(int n) {
        List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
        if(n==1) {
            l.add("()");
            return l;
        }
        for(String st : prent(n-1)) {
            l.add(st+"()");
            l.add("("+st+")");
            if(!(st+"()").equals("()"+st)) {
                l.add("()"+st);
            }
        }
        return l;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code. Tested and working fine.

```
 public class ParanthesisCombination {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
          printParenthesis(3);
     }
     static void printParenthesis(int n){
        printParenthesis("",n,n);       
     }

     static void printParenthesis(String s,int open,int close){
         if(open>close)
            return;
         if(open == 0 && close == 0){
             System.out.println(s);
             return;
         }
         if(open < 0 || close<0)
             return;

         printParenthesis(s + '{',open-1,close);
         printParenthesis(s + '}',open,close-1);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to have ' if(open>close)' condition?

Comment: Found it, at any given point of time, count of '(' to be inserted should not be more than count of  '('.

Answer (score 1):

```
    private static void printA(int open, int close, int max, String out) {
        if(open==close && close==max){
            st.add(out);
            System.out.println(out);
        } else {
            if(open+1<=max){
                printA(open+1, close, max, out+"(");
            }
            if(open>close && close+1<=max){
                printA(open, close+1, max, out+")");
            }
        }
    }
    public static  ArrayList<String>st = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //2 is maximum open/close parenthese
        //i save the output in st(arraylist), 
        printA(0,0,2,"");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in no part of your code you are enforcing the "*no sintax error*" part.

You should change `if(r > 0){...}` for `if(r > l){...}` to enforce that rule; no right parentheses should be printed if there isn't at least 1 left parenteses still "open".

Comment: I think what you said is reasonable, but when I change the condition to if(r>1), I cannot print anything out, I don't know why...will you please have a try?

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's an L(el) not a 1(one). I didn't realize they looked so alike xD I did test it out with `if(r>l)` and it seemed to work ok for 2 and 3 pairs of parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

let us assume total pairs given - 3
to keep valid you only need on opening brace at start and one closing brace at end,
that means ( combinations of 2 pairs ).

so total valid + invalid combinations out of 2 pairs = 3*2 = 6.. these are without repetion..
think of '(' to be a 0 and ')' to be a 1.

0000
1000
0100
**1100**
0010
**1010
0110**
1110
0001
**1001
0101**
1101
**0011**
1011
0111
1111

there can only be 6 possible combinations having 2 0's and 2 1's..
hence for 2 pair total combinations = 6
hence for 3 pairs total valid combinations = 6

Answer (score 0):

```
public class parentheses {
    public static void printPar(int l, int r, char[] str, int count){  //Use recursion method to 
                                                               // print the parentheses

    if(l == 0 && r == 0){     //if there are no parentheses available, print them out  
        System.out.println(str); //Print out the parentheses
    }

    else{
        if(l > 0){    // try a left paren, if there are some available
            str[count] = '(';
            printPar(l - 1, r, str, count + 1); //Recursion
        }
        // Add constraint that a parenthesis is open before inserting a closing paranthesis
        // hence, add l < r - meaning one 'l' is printed before going for an 'r'
        if(r > 0 && l < r){   // try a right paren, if there are some available
            str[count] = ')';
            printPar(l, r - 1, str, count + 1);  //Recursion
        }
    }
}

    public static void printPar(int count){
        char[] str = new char[count*2];   // Create a char array to store the parentheses
        printPar(count,count,str,0);      //call the printPar method, the parameters are the left,
                                    //the right parentheses, the array to store the 
                                    //parenthese, and the counter
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printPar(2);  //
    }

}
```

Comment: Changed from OP's code: `if(r > 0){...}` to `if(r > 0 && l < r){...}`. TESTED and WORKING.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class parentheses {
    public static void printPar(int l, int r, char[] str, int count){
          if(i<0 || r<l) return;
          ...
    }
}
```

You only lost the ending condition. Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ValidParenthesisCombi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final int noOfBraces = 3;
        print(noOfBraces);
    }

    public static void print(int n){
        print("",n,n);
    }
    public static void print( String s, int open, int close){           
        if(open > close){
            return;
        }
        if((open==0)&&(close==0)){
            System.out.println(s);
        }else{
            if(open > 0){
                print(s+"{",open-1, close);
            }if(close > 0){
                print(s+"}",open, close-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```